# jquery ui autocomplete pass a variable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I m using jquery UI for getting suggestions of friend names and id, but the problem is I am  not able to pass user id using autocomplete json function .

```
        $(function() {


    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }

    $( "#recipient" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
             var attm= $('.USERID').val();
                $.getJSON( "modules/messages/sql.php", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term ),

                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                                 var prollNos = $('#recipientid').val()
            $('#recipientid').val(prollNos + ui.item.id + ", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

in which i am trying to pass a: `$('.USERID').val()` as user id , can anyone help me out?

Comment: Where is $('.USERID').val() coming from? More code please.

Comment: m getting a value USERID from a hidden field via jquery val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieve something similar by GET. I use jquery-ui-autocomplete, as source I use: `"source.php?param=something"`. So the final request my source page gets is `"source.php?param=something&term=blabla"`

Comment: with some modifications this method worked , thanks for helping out frnd